# Hook Scripts: what does the "Always execute the script" checkbox or the related "enforce" flag mean?

Tags: windows, tortoise-svn

In the Hook Scripts section of the Settings of TortoiseSVN (version 1.9.2, on Windows 7 x64), there is a checkbox "Always execute the script" in the "Configure Hook Scripts" dialog:

[image: Configure Hook Scripts]

The same checkbox is also present in the Properties dialog for "Local hook scripts":

[image]

What is the exact meaning of that?
In what situations is a hook script not executed unless this checkbox is ticked?

In the help documentation it is not mentioned at all, the snapshots do even not show that checkbox.

The only thing I found out so far is:
It does definitely not suppress the "Approve or reject client-side hook script" prompt.

[image: Approve or reject client-side hook script]

The checkbox is connected to the `enforce` flag of the `tsvn:*hook` Property:

```
type_of_hook  ^/path/to/hook/script  {false|true}  {show|hide}  [enforce]
```

Comment: Look here http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks and perhaps start reading from **Implementing Repository Hooks** down and/or the **Common uses for hook scripts**. Perhaps this is a repository level hook script from the server side and it's triggered only at this level and not the client side as per the documentation.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT, actually it is a client-side hook script as I have to provide a local path to the hook script on my client; I am quite sure this is not a server-side issue, I am even quite sure it is only TortoiseSVN-specific...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I have finally found the purpose of the "Always execute the script" option and of the `enforce` flag:

In case a hook script fails, a dialog like the following might appear (depending on the hook; the example shows a pre-commit hook script without `enforce` flag that returned a non-zero exit code):

[image]

You might already have recognised the button "Retry without hooks".

In case you set the `enforce` flag for the hook, the retry button disappears:

[image]

This is the only situation where I noticed a difference when flag `enforce` is set. I will return to here as soon as I find more effects of the always-execute option.